# How to write to stdout with gnuplot's print statement?

Tags: gnuplot

When I use the following in my script, gnuplot will print `test` to `stderr`:

```
print "test"
```

However, I want to write `test` to `stdout` as only errors should be  written to `stderr`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As stated in the gnuplot docs (type `help print` in interactive gnuplot console):

> The output file can be set with set print.

So, let's look up `set print`:

> Without `"<filename>"`, the output file is restored to `<STDERR>`. The
>   `<filename>` `"-"` means `<STDOUT>`.

So simply add a `set print "-"` at the top of your gnuplot script and everything printed by the `print`-statement is written to `stdout`.