# Redirect Gnuplot Error Messages

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

I'd like to redirect gnuplot error messages (that are normally displayed in the gnuplot terminal) to a file for logging. Is there any way to do this?

**Example:** if I type

```
gnuplot> Hi!
```

in the gnuplot terminal, Then I get

```
gnuplot> Hi!
         ^
         invalid command
gnuplot>
```

Is there any way to redirect "^\ninvalid command" into another file, e.g. err.txt?

**Context:** I'm using gnuplot embedded in a c++ application using [gnuplot-iostream](http://www.stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/) by Dan Stahlke. It works great! But I have no idea how to get error messages from this pipe, so this would be a good work-around.

Comment: Only a vague comment rather than an answer but it may help. I guess `gnuplot` uses `GNU readline` - I may be wrong. Try tagging with `readline` to attract experts in that and maybe try Googling "readline error handling". Sorry, just trying to guess or help with a possible way forward.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly if this applies on your `c++` application (probably not), but I thought I'd mention anyway. If you do:

```
[user@server]$ gnuplot 2> err.txt
gnuplot> Hi!
gnuplot> exit
[user@server]$ cat err.txt

G N U P L O T
Version 5.0 patchlevel 1    last modified 2015-06-07 

Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2015
Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type set to 'aqua'
     ^
     invalid command
```

Maybe you could incorporate something like this. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one can achieve this internally within Gnuplot without tinkering with the source code.

The message "invalid command" is produced in `command.c` by calling the function `int_error` (defined in `util.c`) within which is `stderr` specified explicitly...

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems gnuplot redirects by default both stdout and stderr to stderr.
Instead, terminal file output is send to stdout. Here is an example to check. The content of `tmp.gnu`.

```
print 'some text';
set terminal postscript;
set out
pl sin(x)
```

```
gnuplot tmp.gnu 2>tmp.txt  1>sin.ps
```

`tmp.txt` contains the stdout and `sin.ps` the postscript file.

Check also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27375957/11769765 to use
`set print "-"`, `set print "/dev/fd/2"` or `set print "filename"` to redirect stdout.