# How to prevent a process opened with popen() in C++ from receiving SIGINT signal?

Tags: c++, signals, popen, sigterm

I opened a process(GNUplot) from C++ with the popen() function. When I Ctrl+C to terminate the process, GNUplot also receives SIGINT signal. I want to prevent this from happening as it has an unfavorable effect on what I do. (I prefer to handle the signal with my own signal handler function). How do I do that?

I plot using the `plot '-'` command and iterate through all the values I want to plot. If the gnuplot receives SIGINT in the middle, it might stop plotting in the middle without completing the entire plot. I want it to complete the entire plot. This is the unfavorable effect I have.

Comment: Please explain what is the unfavorable effect thay you want to avoid.

Comment: I finally downvoted your question, because you have not edited it to explain what "unfavorable effect" you want to avoid.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) is running a new shell `/bin/sh -c` on the command string.

The [`trap` builtin](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) of the shell is handling signals; with an empty first argument it is ignoring it. So you could do

```
 FILE* f = popen("trap '' TERM INT; gnuplot", "w");
```

BTW, [POSIX `trap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/trap.html) requires the signals to be named without `SIG` prefix.

But that won't work, since `gnuplot` itself is *explicitly* [handling signals](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/mailman/message/12327345/). There is no way to avoid that outside of `gnuplot`. But take advantage of the [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) nature of [`gnuplot`](http://www.gnuplot.info/): download its source code, study it, and patch it to fit your bizarre needs. FWIW, `SIGINT`  and `signal` appear in several places in the source code of `gnuplot-5.0.5`.

However, you should consider (instead of using `popen`) to call the low level system calls explicitly (`fork`, `execve`, `pipe`, `dup2`, `waitpid`, `signal` ...). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) for details.

---

I strongly suspect that your question is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You don't explain what "unfavorable effect" you actually want to avoid, and I am guessing you might avoid it otherwise.

> I plot using the `plot '-'` command and iterate through all the values I want to plot. If the gnuplot receives SIGINT in the middle, it might stop plotting in the middle without completing the entire plot. I want it to complete the entire plot.

Actually you might set up two or three pipes (one for input, one for output, perhaps one for stderr, as seen on `gnuplot` side) for `gnuplot`. You need to go the low level system calls (explicit calls to [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) etc etc...). Your program should then have some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (probably based upon [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...). And you would send a `print "DONE"` [command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27375956/841108) to gnuplot after every `plot '-'` (don't forget to initialize with the appropriate `set print '-'` or have another pipe for the *stderr* of `gnuplot`). Your event loop would then catch that `DONE` message to synchronize. Read also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582916/841108).

Comment: My suggestion is to avoid `popen`  and use the lower-level system calls.

Comment: I made a typo, it is `trap '' TERM` not `SIGTERM`; but I do recommend avoiding `popen` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem as you. I'm using tc command with -batch parameter and I need to keep it alive until it exits after reaching limit and is closed. My problem was that I was running two asynchronous popen processes and after throwing an exception, second process was killed. A lot of memory dumps etc. After finding this problem and fixing it I can now handle SIGINT, SIGTERM, ctrl+c without tc proces knowing anything about it. No need for traps or anything similar.